# Firebase: Error: Key content was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead."

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Trying firebase for the first time. Got the whole thing working in a plunkr here: 
    http://plnkr.co/3WIrBn

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

app.factory('chatMessages',["$firebaseArray",function($firebaseArray){
var ref = new Firebase('https://scanapp.firebaseIO.com/tut');
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
}]);


app.controller('MyController'['$scope','chatMessages',function($scope,chatMessages){

$scope.test = 'hello world';
$scope.user = "anonymouse";
$scope.messages = chatMessages;

$scope.addMessage = function(){
    $scope.messages.$add({
        from: $scope.user,
        content: $scope.message
    });
    $scope.message = '';
};


}]);
```

I tried following their tutorials on their site, did their quick start stuff as well as read the docs thoroughly, but I keep getting the error above:

"Error: Key content was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead."

I can get it all working in the above plunk, so I understand the concepts. Then I copied that same code from the plunk, and CDN links to my project, same error. Im using ionic framework for a web-based app. Angular and everything is still working fine,I just get the error when trying to hit the "add" button to run the function.

**UPDATE**: It definitely has something to do with inputs. If I set the "from" and "content" key and field as strings rather than bound to $scope, it works:

```
    $scope.addMessage = function(){
    $scope.messages.$add({
        from: 'test',
        content: 'stuff'
    });
    $scope.message = '';
};
```

But obviously that isn't useful other than sending the same data over and over again.

Comment: So the problem only occurs when you run the code in Ionic? In that case, please tag with ionic and phonegap/cordova. Searching for previous questions with those tags, might also be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase+cordova

Comment: There's a lot more you can test here. First of all, you have `message` in two places--in the ng-repeat and in the ng-model--so renaming one of those would be a good first step. Second, Angular recommends against using ng-model with a direct ref and suggests always using an object (like `ng-model="message.text"`), another trivia point. Log the values on $scope inside the $add function, see if ng-change is firing before the form submit, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have your $scope.messages in a form. The form creates a new scope. Remove the form and replace your button with the following:`<button ng-click="addMessage()">Add</button>`
This doesn't create a new scope and your message will be added successfully to your firebase.
At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the models to the function

```
 $scope.addMessage = function(user,message) {
          $scope.messages.$add({
            user,
            body: message
          });
          //RESET MESSAGE
          $scope.msg = "";
        }
```

and on your form

```
     <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Name</span>
          <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user" >
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Message</span>
          <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="message" >
        </label>

   <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="addMessage(user,message)">  Send  </button></pre>
```

Best of luck.